# Selenium Webdriver: Can't access element containing onclick and text attributes

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The `HTML` page I'm working with contains the following element:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none; font-weight:normal;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="CreateNewServiceItemApproved();">  
<img src="icons/ui/addnew.png">  
<span style="color:#000">Add New Incident</span>  
</a>
```

I need to click on it but receiving

```
 org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element
```

error.
Tried to locate it with following commands:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("a[@onclick='CreateNewServiceItemApproved()']")).click();  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Add New Incident')]"));
```

Why can't I locate this element?
What's wrong here?

Comment: try adding an id to the element and finding by id. Is the element inside an ifame?

Comment: How can I add an id to the element? I'm writing automation test code for this page, not creating the page itself. And yes, it is inside some iframe. The entire HTML page contains several iframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the element is inside a `iframe`, you need to `switch`to the iframe first:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("iframeId")));
```

and then find the `<a>` element.

Iframe can be found by `id`, `xpath` or the usual methods.

When processing is donde, you could need to switch to default content with:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```